# Google apps script method getDocumentProperties returns null

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using document properties in my google apps script to store the mysql database connection string and get the error TypeError: Cannot call method "setProperties" of null at line 2 not sure what the reason might be.

```
  dbmysqlconndev = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  dbmysqlconndev.setProperties({
   'mysqlUrl': 'jdbc:mysql://dbserverdev;databaseName=sample',
   'mysqlUser': 'username',
   'mysqlPassword': 'password'});
  var keys = dbmysqlconndev.getKeys();
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[i]);
  }

var mysqlurl = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[0]);
var mysqlusr = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[1]);
var mysqlpwd = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, as the error message says, that `dbmysqlconndev` is null. Now, what would `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()` return null? Let's read its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getdocumentproperties):

> It is only available if the script is published and executing as an add-on or if it is bound to a Google file type. When document properties are not available this method returns null.

So that would be why: are you probably executing this as a stand-alone script. Use `getScriptProperties` instead of `getDocumentProperties`.

Comment: I am trying to create a script library for my MySQL database connectionstring and call the function DBConn() from other scripts.

Comment: dbmysqlconndev = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  dbmysqlconndev.setProperties({
   'mysqlUrl': 'jdbc:mysql://dbtest;databaseName=test',
   'mysqlUsr': 'un',
   'mysqlPwd': 'pd'});
  var keys = dbmysqlconndev.getKeys();
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[i]);
  }

  var msurl = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[0]);
  var msusr = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[1]);
  var mspwd = dbmysqlconndev.getProperty(keys[2]);
function DBConn() { 
 var du = msurl;
 var u = msusr;
 var p = mspwd;
 return du;
 return u;
 return p;}